# regex to grab from char/string to another

Tags: php, regex

i have this text :

```
blablablabla,"<p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>",blablabla
```

and i want to grab this:

```
"<p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>"
```

what is a good way of doing this? (using regex only)
thanks :)

i tried this:

```
[^,]*
```

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
".*?"
```

only this should work

everything between `""`

or `"<p>.*?</p>"`

if you want to start with `"<p>` and end with `</p>"`

Comment: Watch out for greedyness - this will match `this is my string", and it is great, "because I say so` in `foo, "this is my string", and it is great, "because I say so", bar`. Use `.*?` for lazyness instead (stop matching as soon as possible)

Comment: Yes, it's true. Thanks for the tip. Post eddited

Answer (score 0):

Why regex only? You can get this easily with:

```
$parts = explode(',', $string);
$p = $parts[1];
```

Comment: This looks... brittle. Also it is not what OP asked.

Comment: Care to explain why it's "brittle"? I'm also aware it's not what the OP asked for, but they may not be aware they can accomplish this without using a regular expression.

Comment: The use case for that solution will be very narrow and will break very fast. It only needs one single `,` to break the above.

Comment: To be fair, one extra `<p>`, `</p>` or `"` could break any of the answers provided. The OP says "I have this text", not "I have text that looks like this but may have extra whatever in there."

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you want, but `/"<p>(.)+<\/p>"/` would probably fit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following,

```
$str = 'blablablabla,"<p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>",blablabla ';

preg_match('/"<p>.+?<\/p>"/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Returns,

```
Array
(
    [0] => "<p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>"
)
```

Comment: OP also wants the quotes